# iphone sdk : Break chinese sentence into words and letters

Tags: ios, nsstring, chinese-locale, word-processor

I have Chinese news feed and I want to break the sentence into smaller chunks to pass to the API.

How can I do it in ios? I have set character length of 50 characters for English language.

Currently I am using `rangeOfString:` function to find dot, comma and break into sentence.

```
NSString *str  = nil, *rem = nil;

str = [final substringToIndex:MAX_CHAR_Private];
rem = [final substringFromIndex:MAX_CHAR_Private];
NSRange rng = [rem rangeOfString:@"?"];
if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
    rng = [rem rangeOfString:@"!"];
    if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
        rng = [rem rangeOfString:@","];
        if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
            rng = [rem rangeOfString:@"."];
            if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
                rng = [rem rangeOfString:@" "];
            }
        }
    }
}
if (rng.location+1 + MAX_CHAR_Private > MAXIMUM_LIMIT_Private) {
    rng = [rem rangeOfString:@" "];
}

if (rng.location == NSNotFound) {
    remaining = [[final substringFromIndex:MAX_CHAR_Private] retain];
}
else{
    //NSRange rng = [rem rangeOfString:@" "];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:[rem substringToIndex:rng.location]];
    remaining = [[final substringFromIndex:MAX_CHAR_Private + rng.location+1] retain];
}
```

This is not working correctly for chinese and japanese characters.

Answer (score 1):

Check NSLinguisticTagger, It should work with Chinese:

From Apple: "The NSLinguisticTagger class is used to automatically segment natural-language text and tag it with information, such as parts of speech. It can also tag languages, scripts, stem forms of words, etc."

Apple documentation [NSLinguisticTagger Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also see [NSHipster NSLinguisticTagger](http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/).

Also see [objc.io issue 7](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/linguistic-tagging.html)

Comment: "If you’re on iOS, then you are currently (as of iOS 7) limited to English only. On OS X (as of 10.9/Mavericks) you have a slightly larger list available; the method +[NSLinguisticTagger availableTagSchemesForLanguage:] lists all schemes available for a given language. The likely reason for limiting the number on iOS is that the resource files take up a lot of space, which is fine on a laptop or desktop machine, but not so good on a phone or tablet."  Got this from a tutorial, Do you have any other option? Plz share

Answer (score 0):

NSString provides that out of the box with NSStringEnumerationBySentences enumeration option:

```
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                           options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences
                       usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSString *sentence = [substring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSpaceSet];
        // process sentence
    }
];
```